# How can I arrange data in different columns (for different constituents) from one?

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, dataframe

I have a data file that has all the values for various constituents at different dates in same column. I want different constituents in different columns. Following is the example data format. I want Aluminium, Berrylium and other variables in that column to be in different columns. The data file is attached.

```
SITE_NAME   SAMP_DATE_TIME      SAMPLE      Value   Units   METHOD_CATEGORY
SITE-7-1    10/04/1988 00:00:00 Aluminum    150     ug/L    INORGANIC
SITE-7-1    10/04/1988 00:00:00 Aluminum    150     ug/L    INORGANIC
SITE-7-1    10/04/1988 00:00:00 Beryllium   5       ug/L    INORGANIC
SITE-7-1    10/04/1988 00:00:00 Beryllium   5       ug/L    INORGANIC
```

Data : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SUhYd21U5iQmilABNwoaIXLfsc7Mo6dW

The output I am trying to get is:

```
SITE_NAME   SAMP_DATE_TIME  Aluminum    Beryllium   Bromide Bromomethane    Chloride    Hexachlorobenzene   Isosafrole  Zinc
SITE-7-1    10/4/1988 0:00   150        5           10      7250            10          10                  75
SITE-7-1    12/29/1988 0:00  150        5           10      8100            10          10                  16
SITE-7-1    5/10/1989 0:00   150        5           1000    10              8100        10                  10          16
```

Comment: So do you want your columns to be something like after applying oneHotEncoder? meaning: $SITE_NAME, ..., Aluminum, Beryllium, Value$ and then fill these columns for each row with 0s and 1?

Comment: I need the 'Value' and 'Units' for each sample.

Comment: could you provide the columns and rows names of the table you are aiming to get?

Comment: Hi , I am trying to get it in the form   as below:                                                     
  SITE_NAME SAMP_DATE_TIME ALUMINIUM(ug/L) Berilium(ug/L) Chloride (ug/l) and so on …

Comment: But there are duplicates of the same samples in your data. For instance the first and second rows are totally the same.

Comment: Yes, I want those values listed in different rows for different timestamp and drifferent columns for different parameter

Comment: I mean, even the timestaps are the same for some rows. 
Could you depict the actual output of the tables in the question? just like your current table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is passing 6 days from your question and I didn't want to waste your chance of getting an appropriate response by answering. So, my solution might be naive.

**Step 1**: Changing the categorical data of column `Sample` to numerical

```py
dictionary = {'SITE_NAME':['SITE_7_1', 'SITE_7_1','SITE_7_1'], 
'SAMP_DATE_TIME':['10/04/1988 00:00:00', '10/04/1988 00:00:00', ' 10/04/1988 00:00:00'],
 'SAMPLE':['Aluminium','Aluminium','Beryllium'],
 'Value':[150, 150,5]} 
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.DataFrame(dictionary) 
X = dataset.iloc[:,:].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder() #Creating an object from LabelEncoder class
X[:,2] =labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,2])
```

Result so far:

```
array([['SITE_7_1', '10/04/1988 00:00:00', 0, 150],
       ['SITE_7_1', '10/04/1988 00:00:00', 0, 150],
       ['SITE_7_1', ' 10/04/1988 00:00:00', 1, 5]], dtype=object)
```

**Step 2** Adding the dummy variables as columns

```py
dummies = pd.get_dummies(dataset['SAMPLE'])   
df = pd.concat([dataset, dummies], axis=1)  #concating the dataset and the dummies
```

The result so far:

```
  SITE_NAME        SAMP_DATE_TIME     SAMPLE  Value  Aluminium  Beryllium
0  SITE_7_1   10/04/1988 00:00:00  Aluminium    150          1          0
1  SITE_7_1   10/04/1988 00:00:00  Aluminium    150          1          0
2  SITE_7_1   10/04/1988 00:00:00  Beryllium      5          0          1
```

**Step 3:** filling the dataframe

The logic for filling the values in their corresponding columns is as follows :

```py
for i in range(len(df)): 
    if df.iloc[i]['SAMPLE'] == 'Aluminium': 
         df.at[i, 'Aluminium'] = df.iloc[i]['Value']
```

If we want to apply this to the whole dataset, we can change that `Aluminium` each time for different samples
After this, you can groupby your dataframe to have the rows based on `SITE_NAME` or whatever you want.
feel free to ask if there is any vague point here.

**Filling in the whole table**

```py
samples = list(df['SAMPLE'].unique()) #storing all the unique values of the SAMPLE column
```

Creating a dictionary of samples as keys and their values as values:

```py
dictionary = {}
df_new = df.groupby(['SAMPLE'], as_index=False).mean() #dataframe in which `SAMPLE` is grouped.
for i in range(len(df_new)):
    dictionary[df_new.iloc[i]['SAMPLE']] = df_new.iloc[i]['Value']
```

now dictionary equals:
`{'Aluminium': 150, 'Beryllium': 5}`
Now we can fill in the table:

```py
for sample in samples: 
    for i in range(len(df)): 
        if df.iloc[i][str(sample)] == 1:
            df.at[i, str(sample)] = dictionary[str(sample)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. However the data file I am working with, has more than 50 samples. Is there a way that we could just create column heading based on categories (sample names in 'SAMPLE' column).

Comment: You're welcome :)
I added the rest of code to the end of my answer.